# Picmonkey collage layout Javascript

Tags: html, layout

I want to replicate the dynamic drag-drop layout similar to

http://www.picmonkey.com/ collage,

where you can drag an item on the edges of the container and place it and the layout adjusts accordingly.

Do you know of any algorithm?

Comment: Have you looked into JavaScript and JavaScript frameworks like jQuery or Dojo?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/05/dojo-drag-n-drop-redux/

There are many more examples like this if you search in google. Pick anyone and you are good to go.

Comment: Hi, its not the drag and drop I need, i need a algorithm for the layout which is been created dynamically depending on where the item is dropped. Any idea about any algorithm?